Samsung Galaxy M30s not booting the firmware but possible to boot into Recovery/Download Mode. How to get access to internal storage?
I have a long history with my Samsung Galaxy M30s changing firmware, installing TWRP with Magisk, removing TWRP, and only using Magisk...
The phone worked well for a very long time. Yesterday, it restarted automatically (which happened in the past rare times) but then it got stuck in reboot.
I can boot into recovery and download mode, but the phone is not booting into the firmware. It is either stuck at the Samsung logo or restarting again. I flashed ROM via Odin again, with and without patched Magisk. On some reboots, the phone is booting into firmware and my background and parts of the UI are visible. One time, the message for updating apps appeared, but the phone did not finish this process, and every time it is crashing latest at that time and started to reboot. Connected via USB to Windows, the phone is visible in the device manager and is also listed as device in adb, but the device is unauthorized.
Any ideas/solutions to fix that or to get access to the internal storage of my device to save app data and personal stuff?

is phone encrypted?

I have set a pin to access the UI. If that is what you mean, then yes.

If the phone crashes at different times in the boot process this may indeed date a hardware problem. Considering the age if your phone a bad battery would be a possible reason. Have you tried booting your phone while connected to a charger? Another option would be placing the phone switched of in a cool but not frozen environment and then check if the phone runs longer before crashing.

Did put the phone for a short time into the fridge and after that i went it out, put a cooling pack underneath it. first start it was stuck at samsung logo. made a restart and then it booted completely. very surprisingly. @Robert: thank you for that advice.
lost root at the moment. any suggestions what is a good way to save all data now?

As the cooling solution has worked your phone may have problems with "high" CPU load (may be because of an aging CPU that does no longer work stable with high CPU frequency). I would go for the strategy: backup in many different ways. If you haven't done it already enable developer menu and adb. Then copy all data you can access to your PC, then I would backup each app individually via adb backup (not that you may not be able to restore it on a new device). Finally I would try to restore root access and make a full backup. Always only use the phone for a short time and then let it rest.
